# Qt: How to remove the checkered patterns from large images (of comics)?

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside6, qt6

I have a black and white image from a comic that I'm trying to view in a `QGraphicsView`, but there's this "checkered" pattern on the image when viewing it zoomed out. How do I remove it? Some image viewers I've viewed the image on were able to completely remove or lessen the effect to a degree. However, I can't find a way to do it with `Qt`. I don't even know what that effect is called to look for a way.
MRE:

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6 import QtGui
from PySide6 import QtCore

app = QtWidgets.QApplication()

view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(QtGui.QPixmap("path/to/image"))
scene.addItem(item)
view.setScene(scene)
view.fitInView(item, QtCore.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio)
view.show()

app.exec()
```

image: [1.jpg](https://up.ovpn.to/file/WXOVIgKzRKBvGDtwC1MSB8X7JMhDVSHs1vm4aiCO/1.jpg) (1.3 MiB)

Comment: The issue is that the image already has a pixel pattern (known as [*halftone*](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone)) that for obvious reasons doesn't play well with scaling due to [aliasing](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing) issues, even if QGraphicsPixmapItem by default uses antialiasing. Even setting the QPainter `Antialiasing` and `SmoothPixmapTransform` flags to the view might not suffice, especially when the scale factor resulting from `fitInView()` is very close to 1. A possibility could be to use a [QGraphicsBlurEffect](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgraphicsblureffect.html) with a narrow blur ratio.

Comment: @musicamante thank you for the reply. While it did remove the effect, the image looks noticeable blurry (obviously). Looking up on removing the halftone pattern, I stumbled upon [this thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/62653/image-sharpen-filter) where the answer suggests to first blur the image then sharpen it. Do you happen to know of a way to sharpen the image with `PySide`? I can't seem to find a solution for this with `Qt`/`PySide`, and while I might be able to use another Python library, I was wondering if there's a way with `PySide` I failed to find.

Comment: Remember that PySide (as PyQt) is just a *binding* to Qt. If Qt doesn't provide a feature, PySide won't along with it. Qt doesn't provide advanced image processing, as it's not within its purposes. You might want to look into opencv and see if it provides something for that.